# Analysing Javascript from other page to emulate POST request

Tags: javascript

There  is a page with a form. When I press the "send" button, two values `next.x` and `next.y` are added to the POST request.

How do I find out where these values are coming from? Without those values the POST request is not accepted by the page.

I searched all files but I could not find any `next.x` anywhere. I tried different javascript debuggers and there is a function triggered when the submit button is pressed. But I could not find those values there either.

Also after the script is executed the values still not in the form. I checked input fields and target url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're using an `input` with `type="image"`, a sort of "graphical submit control", to submit the form. Change it to a normal `<input type="submit"...`, style it with CSS, and you'll be getting what you want.

[Read up on what the spec says here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1)